# Cannot run the macro… the macro may not be available in this workbook VBA

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling, command

My question at hand is why do these Macros for creating Menu Command buttons work on my personal computer (Excel 2010/2016), but generate macro may not be available messages on my work one.  My only thoughts are it's relative to the bit /configuration of my work laptop, some various complier issue tied to old VBA libraries, assignment references being missed, & something random related to private Subs.

**Macros in This Workbook**.  The coding is done in This Workbook, Module, & User Form (Command Button) . The VBA essentially programs a new button on the Excel Ribbon (Menu Commands) that when you click it an user form will generate. However, this does not happen with the VBA error.  In overall, the coding is very sound. Therefore, I believe the errors I'm getting are tied to system/configuration items.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
RemoveMenuItem
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  AddMenuItem
    'frmMain.Show

End Sub
```

**MODULE**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Selectfile()

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\brian\Desktop\practice file2.xlsm")
End Sub


Sub AddMenuItem()
    Dim cmbWorkSheetMenuBar As CommandBar
    Dim cmbControl As CommandBarControl

    Set cmbWorkSheetMenuBar = Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar")
    Set cmbControl = cmbWorkSheetMenuBar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, temporary:=True) 'adds a menu item to the Menu Bar
    With cmbControl
        .Caption = "Show Form" 'names the menu item
        .OnAction = "ShowTheForm" 'runs the specified macro
        .FaceId = 1098 'assigns an icon to the dropdown

    End With
 End Sub

Sub RemoveMenuItem()
    On Error Resume Next 'in case the menu item has already been deleted
    Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls("Show Form").Delete 'delete the menu item
End Sub

Sub ShowTheForm()
    frmMain.Show

End Sub
```

**UserForm Click Code**

```
Option Explicit



Private Sub btnOne_Click()
   Application.FindFile



End Sub
```

Comment: (a) Is it the same **workbook** being used on the personal computer and the work computer, or just the same **code**?  If just the same code, have you checked your other code settings - e.g. when you talk about "UserForm Click Code" is that actually in a form called "UserForm" or is it in "frmMain" - etc.  (b) When do you receive the error?  When clicking btnOne?  Or when opening the workbook?  Or when clicking the button on the Menu?  Or at some other time?

Comment: (A) The workbook coding is about 100% same on both systems. The only difference is the file name in the Open workbook procedure. (This is not the issue at hand) --The UserForm (Name) is renamed FrmMain. (B) The error Macro not found --occurs when clicking the actual Menu Command Button -with the caption Show Form. The PROBLEM is the userform won't populate onto the screen. This makes me believe it's related to the bit type of the computer, or VBA can't process private subs.  Maybe it's something else . I would love to know your thoughts.